# Find correct place to insert new hi-score record

Tags: sql, algorithm, sorting, insert

Given the table:

```
ArcadeScores
------------
ID
GameID
UserID
Score
Milliseconds
Rank
```

Where `Rank` is > 0 and calculated as the index of `Score DESC then by Milliseconds ASC` (best score is always top, in case of equal score it's ranked by whoever did it fastest).

Storing `Rank` is required as it allows me to perform fast queries such as `How many top 3 scores does userID 5 have?`.

Recalculating the `Rank` for a `GameID` when a new score is inserted by ordering all the records and looping each one updating the rank works OK, but looping through every record and performing an update query on every record slows down when you have thousands of records.  For a popular game (especially a fast game where a single user might be posting a new score every 3 seconds or so), this is too costly.

Given a new score record, I need to work out which position it should be inserted into.  If our new record is going to be rank `45` we can then increment every record above it by one which is a far cheaper operation:

```
UPDATE ArcadeScores SET ScoreRank = ScoreRank + 1 WHERE gameID = " + myGameID + " AND ScoreRank >= 45
```

The difficulty I'm having is working out the rank of a record of the record to insert.  On `Score` or `Milliseconds` alone it's fairly easy, but I'm struggling to make it discover the correct `Rank` as a combination of both.

How many score records there are for a game is a known value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need a query or maybe you can use a function? Try this query - if i understood order in your table correctly, it will give a rank for the new row with values inserting_score and inserting_milliseconds:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) + 1 FROM ArcadeScores 
WHERE Score > inserting_score OR (Score = inserting_score AND Milliseconds < inserting_millisecondes)
```

---

Oh, forgot about GameID :)

```
SELECT COUNT(1) + 1 FROM ArcadeScores 
WHERE GameID = inserting_gameid AND (Score > inserting_score 
OR (Score = inserting_score AND Milliseconds < inserting_millisecondes))
```

Comment: Brilliant thank you!  Was doing it from the wrong angle completely, your way is great!